# Can't overthink my daunting, challenging ask

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

RILFYSXHTWBNLFUFTWNQAFHFTMTWNQYSRTTWBNLFUFTWYSFEUFTWBNLFHFBNTWXHYSHTAFSDTWUFFEKQYSSDUFTWBNLFUFTWFEHFBFUFTWYSNQTWHFTWFEUFHFRTYCQFTWFEYSFETWRIBNHFBNUFTWYSFETWRTHFSDSHYS

> Groups of two

Comment: I got it, but I don't get it.

Comment: @codewarrior0 do you mean you decoded the code, but aren't sure what the decoded text is asking you to do?

Comment: No one can get it you should drop some hints

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker I added a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt at the answer, which is an image:

> [image: IN state flag]

Reasoning:

> Note the frequent occurance of "TW" after sets of even-numbered letter counts, suggesting a substitution cipher of length 2. (Or just read the hint)
>  Running this through a Substution Cipher Reducer of length 2 and changing the E's to spaces gives:
>  ABCD FBG HIJK HCL FBG CMG FBJF DCNIO GMPCOG FBG MJQG CH J MGJLRS MCM AFJFG CM LJOTC

> Solving this cryptogram gives:
>  RILFYSXHTWBNLFUFTWNQAFHFTMTWNQYSRTTWBNLFUFTWYSFEUFTWBNLFHFBNTWXHYSHTAFSDTWUFFEKQYSSDUFTWBNLFUFTWFEHFBFUFTWYSNQTWHFTWFEUFHFRTYCQFTWFEYSFETWRIBNHFBNUFTWYSFETWRTHFSDSHYS
>  S H O W   T H E   F L A G   F O R   T H E   O N E   T H A T   W O U L D   E N C O D E   T H E   N A M E   O F   A   N E A R B Y   N O N   S T A T E   O N   R A D I O
>  SHOW THE FLAG FOR THE ONE THAT WOULD ENCODE THE NAME OF A NEARBY NON-STATE ON RADIO

Next we create the key from what we know:

> A HF
>  C KQ
>  D SD
>  E UF
>  F NQ
>  G TM
>  H LF
>  I SH
>  L AF
>  M BF
>  N FE
>  O YS
>  R RT
>  S RI
>  T BN
>  U HT
>  W XH
>  Y QF
>  _ TW

Now at this point we have already noticed that the title

> is an acronym for CO MD CA, some U.S. states, in alignment with the message referencing a 'state'.

The next step is to stare at this key for an hour trying to make sense of it.

> Eventually I started trying rot-n shifts on it, assuming the key had to stand for something meaningful.

Finally, I hit on

> rot 21, which lines up with the title theme so far. Here's a rot-21 version of the key data:
>  A CA
>  C FL
>  D NY
>  E PA
>  F IL
>  G OH
>  H GA
>  I NC
>  L VA
>  M WA
>  N AZ
>  O TN
>  R MO
>  S MD
>  T WI
>  U CO
>  W SC
>  Y LA
>  _ OR

> The next step is to try to fill in the gaps, as at this point nothing in the data suggests a "non-state on radio".
>  We notice #1 and #3, CA and NY, are very populous states. Comparing to a [list of US states by population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_population), everything lines up and we can fill the gaps:
>  A CA
>  B TX
>  C FL
>  D NY
>  E PA
>  F IL
>  G OH
>  H GA
>  I NC
>  J MI
>  K NJ
>  L VA
>  M WA
>  N AZ
>  O TN
>  P MA
>  Q IN
>  R MO
>  S MD
>  T WI
>  U CO
>  V MN
>  W SC
>  X AL
>  Y LA
>  Z KY
>  _ OR
>  At this point we notice an easter egg - the title, CO MD CA decodes to ASU, which is USA backwards.

Now we have a full key if we rotate everything back:

> A HF
>  B YC
>  C KQ
>  D SD
>  E UF
>  F NQ
>  G TM
>  H LF
>  I SH
>  J RN
>  K SO
>  L AF
>  M BF
>  N FE
>  O YS
>  P RF
>  Q NS
>  R RT
>  S RI
>  T BN
>  U HT
>  V RS
>  W XH
>  X FQ
>  Y QF
>  Z PD
>  _ TW

Going back to the message, we need

> THE FLAG FOR THE ONE (US state) THAT WOULD ENCODE THE NAME OF A NEARBY NON-STATE ON RADIO
>  The most logical nearby non-state is Puerto Rico, or PR. "On radio" implies either morse code or Nato phonetic alphabet, but I had no luck getting either to clue Puerto Rico using the data, or checking all state flags.
>  Perhaps that is the correct route... but I am proposing a different idea:
>  If 'on radio' refers to Nato alphabet codes, "Quebec" is nearby to the US, it is not a state (it's not part of the US), and it IS "on radio"... "Quebec" is the Nato phonetic code for "Q".
>  Even though 'non state' is an odd way to clue a Canadian province, the title DOES say to not overthink this. "nearby non state on radio = Quebec" is certainly simpler than the steps I was taking to try to get Puerto Rico as an answer.
>  So, what US State would encode 'Q'? Looking at our key, the answer is INDIANA (IN).
>  We are asked to show the flag, so the final answer is:
>   [image: IN state flag]

Comment: This is right! It was interesting to see how you figured out that they were state abbreviations. I was expecting that somebody would decode the Caesar cipher initially and see that it was state abbreviations; it was interesting to see how figuring that out was a later step.